# Anybody have issues tapping on cells using Xcode7 UITesting?

Tags: ios, xcode, ui-testing, xcode-ui-testing

Anybody having issues tapping on cells where a lot of cells exist? I keep getting the error "Failed to get refreshed snapshot".

I tried using the recorder but that also seems to freeze. I assume it's trying to cache all the cells in the view.

Example: I have cells for each day on a calendar with accessibilityIdentifiers. I have no problems tapping on the cells using the Identifiers with KIF.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i have. Its about 1 error of 100 tests. Maybe is an apple bug: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/6437. I don't know any workarounds :(

Answer (score 0):

A work around would be to tap screen coordinates as mentioned by taylesworth on [Apple Developer Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/6437)

Example:

```
let coordinate = cell.coordinateWithNormalizedOffset(CGVector(0.5, 0.5))  
coordinate.tap()
```